Manga where the main character is sick and enters a contract engagement to recover from her sickness
Please note that this is from my memory and might not be entirely accurate.
The main character is isekai'd into a novel she read, becoming a brown-haired, green-eyed character. In the novel, the character she inhabits was supposed to die from an illness before the main character of the novel returns home. She ends up in a contractual engagement with a duke (or a similar figure) so she can move into a side house to recover, without ever telling her husband about her illness.

Is this I'm Engaged to an Obsessive Male Lead...?

One day, Veillyn Orlando comes to the realization that she's been living the last 21 years as a side character in a BL novel and is fated to die in one year! In light of this, Veillyn decides to escape her abusive family and live out the rest of her days in peace. However, her only way out is getting engaged to the male lead of the novel, Jellard Lieseltein. He seems like the perfect candidate for a contractual engagement because he's into men, meaning there's no risk of them actually falling in love with each other... But as the two spend more time together, Jellard seems to be falling for Veillyn. Will Veillyn be able to navigate her growing feelings for Jellard while keeping her inevitable death a secret?


A woman from the modern world is reincarnated as Veillyn Orlando, a brown-haired, green-eyed background character in a historical Boys' Love novel she'd read.
Her father, Count Orlando, bought her mother from her parents for the express purpose of producing a male heir, but she gave birth to Veillyn instead and died during childbirth, leaving Veillyn with a father who never wanted or fully accepted her as his daughter. Her father later had a second daughter, Etelina, with a mistress, and Etelina was treated much more favourably than Veillyn.
In the original plot of the novel, Veillyn falls ill with an unknown disease at the age of 22 and dies a little over a year later in the dusty attic that serves as her bedroom. On the day of Veillyn's funeral, Etelina meets a young man named Nellan Chester, who falls in love with her at first sight. This is a key event in the story, as Jellard Lieseltein -- the novel's male lead and son of an archduke -- falls in love with Nellan, forming a love triangle between the three.
When the protagonist wakes up as Veillyn, she's only just become ill, so she knows she has about a year left to live. Although she believes her death is unavoidable, she doesn't want to die in her father's househould like Veillyn did in the novel, so she persuades Jellard to enter into a contractual engagement with her as a means to leave home. She lets him know that she's ill, but downplays the severity of it, and moves into an annex to the main building in the Lieseltein Estate.
You can read the full manhwa at Tappytoon.

thank you very much. been trying to find it for very long.

As I read it, this indeed is what I was looking for, but I have merged the content with another manga.

"Cavalier with the truth" also has a similar plot where fmc is injured (cant move unless using puppet magic). and she is impersonating a noble (who is sick/dying in a wheelchair). in order to serve in the military under his name even though he is crippled.
